# Prove using formal methods

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-proofs

Prove using formal methods

> ∀x ¬(P(x) ∧ Q(X)) --> ∀x(¬P(x) v ¬Q(x))

So I tried this problem

> 1. ∀x ¬(P(x) ∧ Q(X))   P
> 2. ∀x ¬P(x) v ¬Q(X)    Distributing the not.
>    Can I do something like this? I thought the answer was supposed to be much longer than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your proof defeats the point, since your second step just assumes that the statement is true. Try this- assume that for any $x$, $P(x) \land Q(x)$ is false. Then we can't have $P(x)$ be true and $Q(x)$ be true, otherwise, $P(x) \land Q(x)$ would be true, so at least one of the two is false (essentially, we're looking at a truth table for $P$ and $Q$ and eliminating one possibility, where both are true. The other three possibilities have at least one of the two false.) The rest should be apparent.